# parallel.for confusion (collection losing order)

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have a problem in which I am trying to load some files into a database using parallel.for(). My problems is that the file ids that are getting passed to the database function are somehow not correct. That is, the database is returning the wrong data. I tried to verify this by using a concurrent dictionary to add the id/name pairs both with and without parallel. In my mind, the lists should be the same after the loop ends. But they are not. This simulates what I'm doing in a very simplified way.

Does this make sense?:

```
class Program
    {
       ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> _cd = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        static void Main()
        {
            //simulate the situation
            int[] idList = new int[] {1, 8, 12, 19, 25, 99};
            string[] fileList = new string[] {"file1", "file8", "file12", "file19", "file25", "file99"};

            //run in serial first
            ProcessFiles(idList, fileList); 

            //write out pairs to text file
            foreach (var item in _cd)
            {
                var key = _cd.key;
                var val = _cd.value;
                string line = string.Format("fileId is {0} and fileName is {1}", key, val);

                File.AppendAllText(@"c:\serial.txt", line + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            //results of text file (all good): 
            //fileId is 1 and fileName is file1
            //fileId is 8 and fileName is file8
            //fileId is 12 and fileName is file12
            //fileId is 19 and fileName is file19
            //fileId is 25 and fileName is file25
            //fileId is 99 and fileName is file99

            _cd.Clear();

            //now run in parallel
            ProcessFilesInParallel(idList, fileList); 

            //write out pairs to text file  
            foreach (var item in _cd)
            {
                var key = _cd.key;
                var val = _cd.value;
                string line = string.Format("fileId is {0} and fileName is {1}", key, val);

                File.AppendAllText(@"c:\parallel.txt", line + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            //results of text file (1. some, not all, are mismatched and 2. not all elements got added): 
            //fileId is 8 and fileName is file8
            //fileId is 12 and fileName is file19
            //fileId is 19 and fileName is file12
            //fileId is 25 and fileName is file25
        }

        private void static ProcessFiles(int[]Ids, string[] files)
        {
            int fileId = 0;
            string fileName = string.Empty;

            for(var i=0, i<Ids.Count; i++) 
            {
                fileId = Ids[i];
                fileName = GetControlFileMetaDataFromDB(fileId);

                _cd.TryAdd(fileId, fileName);
            }
        }

        private void static ProcessFilesInParallel(int[]Ids, string[] files)
        {
            int fileId = 0;
            string fileName = string.Empty;

            Parallel.For(0, Ids.Count, i => 
            {
                fileId = Ids[i];

                //this is returning the wrong fileName 
                fileName = GetControlFileMetaDataFromDB(fileId);

                _cd.TryAdd(fileId, fileName);
            }

            );
        }

        private void static GetControlFileMetaDataFromDB(int fileId)
        {
            //removed for brevity:
            //1. connect to oracle
            //2. call function, passing file id
            //3. iterate over data reader and look for the filename 

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //strip out filename, add it to collection
                int endPos = reader[0].ToString().IndexOf("txt");
                if (endPos != -1)
                {
                    endPos += 3;
                    int startPos = reader[0].ToString().IndexOf(":\\") - 1; 
                    string path = reader[0].ToString().Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos);
                    sring fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

                    _cd.TryAdd(fileId, fileName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please copy the code into an editor and try to compile it. There is a massive amount of errors. Please fix them and add the `using` directives so that others can examine code.

Comment: I would be especially interested where the `reader` variable comes from. Could it be that there is just one database connection and you are accessing from multiple threads without synchronization.

Comment: It's basic data access code that was "removed for brevity" as I put in the comment. The poster below nailed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

You've declared `fileId` and `fileName` *outside* the Parallel.For, which means the same variable is shared by every iteration.

Since the iterations may very well run in parallel on different threads, you're reassigning variables while another simultaneous iteration may be using them.

What you need to do is move your variable declarations *inside* the loop, so they're local per iteration;

```
Parallel.For(0, Ids.Count, i => 
{
    int fileId = Ids[i];

    //this is returning the wrong fileName 
    string fileName = GetControlFileMetaDataFromDB(fileId);

    _cd.TryAdd(fileId, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something silly and simple. It is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in `ProcessFilesInParallel(int[]Ids, string[] files)` function. Iterations in the `for` loop will be executed in parallel, and you declared `fileId` and `fileName` outside of `for`'s scope, so this variables are shared for all iterations falling in a race condition.

You can fix this problem, moving `fileId` and `fileName` variables inside the `for`:

```
private static void ProcessFilesInParallel(int[] Ids, string[] files)
{
    Parallel.For(0, Ids.Length, i =>
    {
        var fileId = Ids[i];

        //this is returning the wrong fileName 
        var fileName = GetControlFileMetaDataFromDB(fileId);

        _cd.TryAdd(fileId, fileName);
    });
}
```

Also, in title of question **parallel.for confusion (collection losing order)** you says collection loses order. As you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx) the order of execution isn't defined for a parallel loop.